I want to send data using ajax when the value comes out in jsp
The value comes out from JSP. However, I don't know how to send the value as Ajax data.
I tried to print the JSP value and change it, but it failed. What should I do?
What should I put in the data in Ajax?
The output of out.println(name + " : " +obj.toString()); is "name : test_00".
The output of auth.getAttributes() is "{name=test_00}".
And I want it to be sent right away when onload Is this correct?
Please tell me the answer how to do this
<%
if (auth.isAuthenticated())
{
out.println("auth.getErrorMessage() :"+auth.getErrorMessage());
}
else
{
Map<String, Object> attr = auth.getAttributes();

if (attr.isEmpty())
{
out.println("Attribute is empty.");
}
else
{
Collection<String> keys = attr.keySet();
for (String name:keys)
{
Object obj = attr.get(name);

out.println(name + " : " + obj.toString());
out.println("<br>");
}
}
}
%>

<script>
    window.onload  = function() {
    acs();
    }
    
    function acs(){
    $.ajax({
    //url: "/login",
    type : "POST",
    data : '???????', //I don't konw
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    }
    },
    
    });
    }
</script>


Did let jsVar = "<% jsp-output %>";not work?

You said that

The output of auth.getAttributes() is "{name=test_00}".

This output you can add to the ajax data property like this
Map<String, Object> attr = auth.getAttributes();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.accumulateAll(attr);

   $.ajax({
    //url: "/login",
    type : "POST",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data : JSON.stringify(<%=json%>), //{"name":"test_00"}
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    }



Yes thank you so much this is correct ‘<%= auth.getAttributes()%>

$.ajax({
url: "/login",
type: 'post',
data: JSON.stringify('<%=auth.getAttributes()%>'),
contentType: 'application/json',
dataType: 'json',
success: function (data){
console.log(data);
},
error: function (data){
console.log(data);
//console.log("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);
}
});  @PostMapping("/login")
public String login(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> attr){attr.get("name")}

JSON parse error: Cannot construct instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value
In my opinion, the result is now {name=test_00}, so I think an error occurs. I want to change {"name"="test_00"} like this. How can I do it?

Updated the answer.
